# How to extract numbers UNTIL a space is reached in a string using Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I need to pull the code from the following string: 72381 Test 4Dx for Worms.  The code is 72381 and the function that I'm using does a wonderful job of pulling ALL the numbers from a string and gives me back 723814, which pulls the 4 from the description of the code. The actual code is only the 72381. The codes are of varying length and are always followed by a space before the description begins; however there are spaces in the descriptions as well. This is the function I am using that I found from a previous search:

```
Function OnlyNums(sWord As String)          
    Dim sChar As String         
    Dim x As Integer            
    Dim sTemp As String         

    sTemp = ""          
    For x = 1 To Len(sWord)         
        sChar = Mid(sWord, x, 1)            
        If Asc(sChar) >= 48 And _           
          Asc(sChar) <= 57 Then         
            sTemp = sTemp & sChar           
        End If          
    Next            
    OnlyNums = Val(sTemp)           
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the find function.. Example:

[image]

or in VBA [instr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)  and [left()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx)
[image]

Since you know the pattern is always code followed by space just use `left` of the string for the number of characters to the first space found using `instr`. Sample in immediate window above.  Loop is going to be slow, and while it may validate they are numeric why bother if you know pattern is code then space?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I did post an answer as well that works. Again - I should have researched more.

Comment: Make sure you wrap this in a trim statement if you use the formulaic version, Find will find the space, it returns `"72381 "` trim will remove it or you can put `-1` after the `find(" ",C3)` part. Being that you mentioned this is a code, it is probably very important to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If the first character in the description part of your string is never numeric, you could use the VBA `Val(string)` function to return all of the numeric characters before the first non-numeric character.

```
Function GetNum(sWord As String)
    GetNum = Val(sWord)
End Function
```

See the [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296(v=office.15).aspx) of the `Val(string)` function for full details of it's usage.

Comment: I have never seen this before, noted for future use :)

Comment: I find it in`val`uable. Pun intended.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations in C# code, I leave the loop early after finding the first instance of a space character (32). In VBA, you'd use Exit For.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the function altogether and use this:

```
split("72381 Test 4Dx for Worms"," ")(0)
```

This will split the string into an array using " " as the split char. Then it shows us address 0 in the array (the first element)

In the context of your function if you are dead set on using one it is this:

```
Function OnlyNums(sWord As String)
    OnlyNums = Split(sWord, " ")(0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

While I like the simplicity of Mark's solution, you could use an efficient parser below to improve your character by character search (to cope with strings that don't start with numbers).

*test*

```
Sub test()
MsgBox StrOut("72381 Test 4Dx")
End Sub
```

*code*

```
Function StrOut(strIn As String)
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "^(\d+)(\s.+)$"
    If .test(strIn) Then
        StrOut = .Replace(strIn, "$1")
    Else
        StrOut = "no match"
    End If
End With
End Function
```